# How to align ChipGroup items vertically one after the other in dynamic chips adding method

Tags: android, material-design, android-xml, android-chips

[image]

i want to show chips as shown in the figure, but what i am getting is

[image]

Here is my code

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
        android:id="@+id/chipGroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:chipSpacing="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        app:singleSelection="false"
        app:singleLine="false"
        app:flow_verticalAlign="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:flow_horizontalAlign="center"
        android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
        android:gravity="center">

 @BindView(R.id.chipsSkill) ChipGroup chipGroup;

                final Chip chips = (Chip) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_chip, null, false);
      
                chips.setChipIcon(getDrawable(R.drawable.chips_bg));
                chips.setCheckable(true);
                chips.setChecked(false);
                
                if(ArraList.size()>0){
                    for(String s: ArrayList){
                        chips.setText(s.getName());
                        
                    }
                }   chipGroup.addView(chips);
```

How to align ChipGroup items vertically one after the other

Answer (score 1):

we can align chip vertically ,by setting the chip width as match_parent            `android:layout_width="match_parent"`

please refer to this [Is it possible to set Material ChipGroup orientation to VERTICAL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54530257/is-it-possible-to-set-material-chipgroup-orientation-to-vertical)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but its not working as i am setting the chips dynamically.